# find the oldest file based on date in filename in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: awk, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I would like to list some of the oldest files from my GCS storage based timestamp in file name.

File name is something like this
`abcdefghijklmnop_qrstu_vwxyz_table_v2.20190101000000.csv.gz`

I was able to list the latest file based on this command

```
gsutil ls -l gs://bucket_name/folder/* | awk -F\. 'm<$4{m=$4;f=$0} END{print f}
```

but unable to find the right command to list the oldest file based on filename.  sort -kn |head -n1 did not work

```
gsutil ls -l gs://bucket_name/folder/* | awk -F\. 'm<$4{m=$4;f=$0} END{print f}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gsutil ls gs://***/ | awk -F\. 'BEGIN{t=2**64}{if(t>$2){t=$2;m=$0;}}END{print m}'`

Comment: I tried the above but it did not work. I got this error message:

awk: line 1: syntax error at or near *

Comment: @busheriff what is your OS and awk version?

Comment: I am using gsutil on GCP, not sure what Linux version it is but gsutil version command shows below

gsutil version: 4.38

I am accessing it via my windows desktop.

When I executed this command to show latest file it worked perfectly:
gsutil ls -l gs://bucket_name/folder/* | awk -F\. 'm<$4{m=$4;f=$0} END{print f}

Comment: You are executing this command on GCP instance or windows desktop? If it's windows, is it WSL?

Comment: It was on GCP instance instead of Windows

Comment: I see, I assume you are using the default debian OS, so, the awk is `mawk` instead of `gawk`, change `2**64` to some big integer `90190000000000`

Comment: @busheriff please accept it as answer if it solves your problem